# Convert a DateTime Index into just a Date Index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to convert the DateTimeIndex of a DataFrame into a Day Index.
This is my Dataframe:

```
data = pd.read_csv('EURUSD=X.csv')
data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Gmt time'])
data = data.set_index('DateTime')

    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
DateTime                    
2003-04-05 21:00:00 1.12284 1.12338 1.12242 1.12305 29059.0996
2003-04-05 22:00:00 1.12274 1.12302 1.12226 1.12241 26091.8008
2003-04-05 23:00:00 1.12235 1.12235 1.12160 1.12169 29240.9004
2003-05-05 00:00:00 1.12161 1.12314 1.12154 1.12258 29914.8008
2003-05-05 01:00:00 1.12232 1.12262 1.12099 1.12140 28370.6992
```

I tried using:

```py
data['Day'] = data.date()
```

This gives the following error:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'`

I also tried using:

```py
data.groupby(["Day"])["close"]
```

giving me a KeyError: 'Day'

This is my desired output:

```
    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
DateTime                    
2003-04-05  1.12284 1.12338 1.12242 1.12305 29059.0996
2003-04-05  1.12274 1.12302 1.12226 1.12241 26091.8008
2003-04-05  1.12235 1.12235 1.12160 1.12169 29240.9004
2003-05-05  1.12161 1.12314 1.12154 1.12258 29914.8008
2003-05-05  1.12232 1.12262 1.12099 1.12140 28370.6992
```

Comment: pandas does not handle date and time separately. There is no date index, only datetime.

Comment: `data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Gmt time']).dt.date`

Comment: I found a solution which works, all I had to do was use:

'data.index = data.index.normalize()'

to get the desired output:

' Open High Low Close Volume
DateTime     
2003-04-05 1.12284 1.12338 1.12242 1.12305 29059.0996
2003-04-05 1.12274 1.12302 1.12226 1.12241 26091.8008
2003-04-05 1.12235 1.12235 1.12160 1.12169 29240.9004
2003-05-05 1.12161 1.12314 1.12154 1.12258 29914.8008
2003-05-05 1.12232 1.12262 1.12099 1.12140 28370.6992'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is:

```
data.index = data.index.normalize()

    Open    High    Low Close   Volume
DateTime                    
2003-04-05  1.12284 1.12338 1.12242 1.12305 29059.0996
2003-04-05  1.12274 1.12302 1.12226 1.12241 26091.8008
2003-04-05  1.12235 1.12235 1.12160 1.12169 29240.9004
2003-05-05  1.12161 1.12314 1.12154 1.12258 29914.8008
2003-05-05  1.12232 1.12262 1.12099 1.12140 28370.6992
```

Comment: alternatively `data.index = data.index.floor("d")` - both commands floor the date/time to the date. It keeps the data type datetime64, i.e. a DatetimeIndex, with all the functionality that comes with it.